# Can we replace a present perfect continuous by a simple present perfect

Tags: tense

I was wondering about this sentence:

> It has been snowing all day. (It isn't snowing anymore)

If I replace that sentence with this:

> It has snowed for quite a long time. (It isn't snowing anymore, just
> the snow on the ground).

...are they equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following can shed some light here:

Main verbs using the present participle (ending in -ing) form "continuous" tenses (it is snowing, was snowing, has been snowing, will be snowing, etc.). That verb-form implies an on-going process, often leading from one time frame to another: "It was snowing, and..."

Main verbs using the past participle (often ending in -ed or -en, e.g., to snow - snowed; to write - written) imply a more definite end to the action within a particular time-frame: "It snowed." Either verb-form can be altered by context or additional information.

> It has been snowing all day; thankfully, it has stopped.

> It has snowed all day, and is continuing to snow on into the night.

Although each different verb-form has an implied context (continuing or stopped), neither can be forced into an exclusive time frame, especially when additional information can change the time-flow.

One should not be reluctant to provide whatever additional context makes the meaning of a sentence more clear. Language always has some uncertainty about its composition, and how one deals with that uncertainty is what gives language its style.

Answer (score 0):

> It has been snowing all day = It is still snowing or it has just stopped snowing.

> It has snowed for quite a long time = it is not snowing anymore, the moment it stopped raining can be more remote from the moment of speech.

The two sentences are quite different in meaning as far as time is concerned, so no, they are not interchangeable.

Comment: I understand your point, could there be a comment, it may snow again (according the sky, the weather forecast, or even my personal view)?

Comment: When you say remote it has no sense since snow if obviously recent otherwise it would be melting, this answer is based on grammar points in book but not real....

Comment: The snow stays for days in my country :) Depends on the temperature I guess, not on grammar books. I don't understand your first comment.

Comment: You said : the moment it stopped raining or snowing can be more remote from the moment of speech. How do you estimate, evaluate this remoteness?

Comment: Well, that's the point of Present perfect. It is not precise. If it is a precise moment in the past, you use Past simple. [_**The present perfect is used to indicate a link between the present and the past. The time of the action is before now but not specified, and we are often more interested in the result than in the action itself.**_](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: English grammar is a challenge. I have studied it in the University, taught it to some, but I am definitely still a student. I guess I will always be :) So don't lose heart, go on digging. Good luck.

Comment: Why avoiding extended discussions, it is obvious that the answers proposed have to be extended because they are not accurate...

Comment: I go on digging since I teach myself (or since I'm teaching?) I think it useless to explain since the answers in books and forums are often wrong, nobody has an accurate answer, so why answering? maybe for the hell of it...

Comment: Yes, why not adding it to chat.